# How to continue with this Laplace transform approach to the heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to learn how to use Laplace transforms to solve PDE's. I'm now trying to find the general solution of the heat equation.

$$\partial_{xx}u=\partial_{t}u$$
Taking the Laplace transform w.r.t $t$ gives:
$$\partial_{xx}T(x,s)=sT(x,s)-u(x,0)$$
$$\text{Where } T(x,s):=\mathcal L_t[u(x,t)](s)$$

Solving this ODE, again using laplace transforms gives me:

$$T(x,s)=(\frac{1}{2}T(0,s)+T_x(0,s)\frac{1}{2 \sqrt s})e^{\sqrt s x}+(\frac{1}{2}T(0,s)-T_x(0,s)\frac{1}{2 \sqrt s})e^{-\sqrt s x}-(e^{\sqrt s x}-e^{-\sqrt s x})*u(x,0)$$
Where the last $*$ denotes the convolution operator, and $T_x=\partial _xT$

Taking the inverse laplace transform w.r.t $t$ of this equation seems like a mess. I don't know how to deal with all the $\sqrt s$ in the exponentials, nor the one in the first coefficient.

**Am I taking the right approach? How do I continue solving this heat equation?**

Comment: What are your boundary conditions and initial condition?

Comment: I thought that was clear. I'm asking for the general solution, and using laplace transform which always uses $\tau =0$ for whatever $\tau$ we take the laplace transform to. So: $u(x,0), u_x(0,t),u(0,t)$